# How to reduce Android sdk size on hard disk

Tags: android, diskspace

Though hard disk is cheap these days, ssd is still expensive. My Android SDK is taking something like 14Go.

I have installed apis 19,20 and 21, and each is taking around some valuable space (21 uses 9Go!) in the `system-images/` folder.

Is there some cases where I do need 19 and 20 if I already have 21 ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Find detailed descriptions and step-by-step safe way to clean up the sdk folder in my question here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796230/system-images-in-android-sdk-folder-taking-a-lot-of-disk-space-do-we-need-to-ke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need 19 and 20 only if you plan on creating projects targeted (compiled) for those versions. And you most probably do not ;-) Also, avoid downloading everything each release offers if you do not have a specific need for all of them.

Comment: I removed a ton of items and reduced the size from 40+ GB to < 2 GB