# Is Android SDK Dcoumentation used by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to make my Android SDK install as light as possible. I am curious if the documentation stuff is needed for auto-complete in Android studio.

For example. In SDK manager under "Android 6.0 (API23)" there is a "Documentation for Android SDK" item to install. Is this required for Android Studio to do proper auto complete on API classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the auto-complete does not happen using the "Documentation for Android SDK".

It is there for reference when working offline.

E.g. If you write a simple class without documentation, you will get auto-complete for that too.

Hence, the documentation is not used for auto-complete.

*Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34369232/1957401)  for tips on removing unwanted stuff from the Android SDK safely.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any idea what it does use for autocomplete?