# Android SDK cleanup in Studio 2.3.3

Tags: android

I have started Android Studio after 5 months. I have agreed with update to the latest version and then to update the SDK as well. After two hours it seems finished but I have lost at least 10 GB od my hard drive (half an hour ago 30 GB more). I would like to do some clean up but I cannot open standalone manager anymore.

What is current recommended way of this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34369232/1639556

System images takes 49 GB and I want to delete most of them. Shall I stick with commandline `rm -rf`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use your real android device to run the application, you can go ahead and clean up the system images. This will make room in your hard drive and also feel free to delete the unused system api's which you are not using.